# Is there an alternative way to modifying a unique index other than dropping it? And are there any adverse effects from dropping it?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-key

Currently I have a table that has a UNIQUE KEY for ( item_type, transaction_id, startdate ).

I modified this table so it has an additional `timeperiod` column. Before, items per transaction couldn't have a different timeperiod, but now they can have different date ranges.

Example of rows:

```
item_type transaction_id  startdate    timeperiod
1         1              2014-01-01    0
2         1              2014-01-01    0
1         2              2014-02-02    1
```

So right now, it fails to INSERT something like:

```
1         2              2014-02-02    2
```

Because of the UNIQUE INDEX constraint defined.

Is the only way of modifying the UNIQUE KEY, to drop it and re-add it? ala

```
 ALTER TABLE `transactions_items` 
 DROP KEY `types_id` 
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `types_id` 
     (`item_type`, `transaction_id`, `startdate`, `timeperiod` )
```

Also, could there be any adverse effects on the data after dropping it?

Comment: Yes, you need to drop the index and re create it. There should be no effect of this on the data, because the data in the table already conforms to the existing constraints. And the new constraint is just augmenting the existing constraint.

Comment: Is the database being used when you do the change?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson - yes, however it's mostly just `SELECT`s - very rarely do transactions actually happen in this store.. but it's possible an `INSERT` happens during my update.

Comment: Any write operation will be blocked during the index creation if I'm not mistaken.